# How do I output precision and recall metrics from a confusion matrix in pyspark

Tags: list, pyspark, databricks, precision, enumerate

I have created a list 'labels' for the confusion matrix.

```
labels = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
cm = metrics.confusionMatrix().toArray().astype(int)

pd.DataFrame(
    data=cm, 
    columns=labels,
    index=labels
)
```

```
Out: 
<pre>
1   2   3   4   5   6   7
1   311 90  2   0   13  5   36
2   101 220 12  0   58  11  3
3   1   10  306 23  13  78  0
4   0   1   22  423 0   25  0
5   9   26  3   0   364 4   0
6   1   4   58  13  5   319 0
7   19  7   0   0   2   0   404
</pre>
```

Now, I am trying to use the label list and the metrics.recall and metrics.precision to display the results.

```
print('Label       Precision   Recall')
print('------------------------------')
for i, lab in enumerate(labels):
    print(f'{lab:<12}{metrics.precision(i):<12.4f}{metrics.recall(i):.4f}')
```

This is what I would like it to look like:

```
<pre>
Label       Precision   Recall
------------------------------
0                ?           ?
1                ?           ?
2                ?           ?
3                ?           ?
4                ?           ?
5                ?           ?
6                ?           ?
7                ?           ?
</pre>
```

How else can I call precision and recall without using

```
for i, lab in enumerate(labels):
    print(f'{lab:<12}{metrics.precision(i):<12.4f}{metrics.recall(i):.4f}')
```

because this is giving me the error:
java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: 0.0

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I was able to use to accomplish this:

```
print('Label       Precision   Recall')
print('------------------------------')
for label in sorted(labels):
    print(f'{label:<12}{metrics.precision(label):<12.4f}{metrics.recall(label):.4f}')
```

```
<pre>
Label       Precision   Recall
------------------------------
1           0.7036      0.6805
2           0.6145      0.5432
3           0.7593      0.7100
4           0.9216      0.8981
5           0.8000      0.8966
6           0.7217      0.7975
7           0.9120      0.9352
</pre>
```